# Align text to bottom inner part of image in bootstrap grid

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, vertical-alignment

I need to have a grid in bootstrap with `.row`s and `.col`s that would be images `320x320`, inside these images I need the put text with a dark background and some white text, something like [image: this].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially youd have a container with the "position: relative;" style and the footer text would have a "position: absolute; bottom: 0; left: 0" style.  To get the somewhat transparent bg color youd use rgb(0,0,0,.5) where .5 would be half transparent (or opaque).  Below is how you'd do it with bootstrap 3.

The HTML would look similar to this:

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>stuff</h1>
    <p>Some stuff here</p>
        <div class='row'>
            <div class='col-xs-4'>
                <div class='img-container'>
                    <img src="http://a1.dspnimg.com/data/l/509084866423_rd0gX45i_l.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class='img-footer'>
                        <p>Image Footer text</p>
                    </div>    
                </div>        
            </div>
            <div class='col-xs-4'>
                <div class='img-container'>
                    <img src="http://a1.dspnimg.com/data/l/509084866423_rd0gX45i_l.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class='img-footer'>
                        <p>Image Footer text</p>
                    </div>    
                </div>        
            </div>
            <div class='col-xs-4'>
                <div class='img-container'>
                    <img src="http://a1.dspnimg.com/data/l/509084866423_rd0gX45i_l.jpg" alt="" />
                    <div class='img-footer'>
                        <p>Image Footer text</p>
                    </div>    
                </div>        
            </div>            
        </div>
    </div>            
</div>
```

Whereas the Css would look something like this:

```
div[class^="col-"] {
    margin: 0 !important;
    padding: 0 !important;
    border: solid black 5px;
}

.img-container {
    position: relative;

}

.img-container img {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.img-container .img-footer {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0; left: 0;
    padding: 0 10px;   

    width: 100%;

    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.7);   
}
```

Here is a running JSFiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/4498/

Answer (score 1):

A very crude example here, but the basic principle is to set the overlay div to `position: absolute;` and `bottom: 0;`. This will force the element to the bottom of it's container and then set the background colour to an rgba value to make it slightly opaque:

```
.overlay {
    height: 100px;
    width: 320px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Example: http://www.bootply.com/5l6JQRaNdC

Comment: That's almost what I want, but I also need the squares to be separated with 20px in between, is there any way to make this?

Comment: That depends what you expect to happen as the browser width changes.

Comment: I want it to be 3 columns when wide, then 2, and in mobile 1 column.

Comment: What about the width of the images?

Comment: Ideally, they would fill the width of said columns, also the text with dark background.

Comment: To be honest, this question is spiralling out of control and is now well beyond what you originally asked. Sorry but I don't have time to spend any more on this.